# Using build/compiler variables to pass in IP at buildtime, without creating build artifacts

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-flags

**This is not a duplicate question. Current "answers" to this problem use Objective-C, which allows for more expanded `#Define` statements.** The existing suggested solutions result in an IP address *directly changing* within a file; a build artifact I was trying to avoid.

I'm currently building some tests for a mobile app, built in Xcode with swift. This app uses a cloud service to get status of items, and store/retrieve login information.

```
----------      ---------
| Server | ---> | Cloud | 
----------      ---------
```

When testing, however, I use a dummy server running on nodeJS to provide the expected responses, so I don't have to, say, register an account *every* time I want my UI tests to check the registration process.

```
----------      ---------
| Server | ---X | Cloud | 
----------      ---------
     |         ----------
      -------> | nodeJS |
               ----------
```

In order for this to work well on iOS simulator as well as on an external device, I need to specify the IP of the nodeJS server. I have been doing this manually, but I wanted to make it do so automatically.

**Here's the rub:** I want to be able to do this at *runtime*, or at least at buildtime *without artifacts*.

Solutions I've attempted:

1. PList Variables
   I've created a variable in my `info.plist` called `TestServerIP`. I then use a bash script at buildtime to change the value of the variable to my `en0` address:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   localUrl=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)
   plutil -replace TestServerIP -string \"$localUrl\" $SRCROOT/gdocntl/Info.plist
   ```

   The problem with this is that I now have an IP address hardcoded in my .plist file.
2. New `plist` file
   I wanted to simply make a new `plist` file with only the IP var with bash, but you cannot create files outside of xcode and add them to the bundle easily. I started looking into this, but quickly found I'd be trying to do XML search/replacing... [and we all know how well *that* works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/9952260).
3. Swift script
   I then tried using a modified swift script to pull the IP at runtime, from
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/25627545/9952260. The problem here is that when running on a physical iOS device, this grabs the IP of the iDevice, not the machine.

I've been trying to implement a variation of (1), where I instead define `TestServerIP` to be something like `${NODE_JS_IP}`, but I'm not sure how I can define this using Xcode. I've been down a few rabbit holes:

- [Adding variables at build time in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194561/adding-variables-at-build-time-in-xcode) (Only works with `#if` statements, not useful as my IP is not known before the build script runs)
- [Using compiler variables in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804227/using-compiler-variables-in-swift) (according to this, I can't really do anything about my problem)
- https://medium.com/@danielgalasko/change-your-api-endpoint-environment-using-xcode-configurations-in-swift-c1ad2722200e (Really close, but ultimately falls back to using #if statements on pre-defined URLs, not arbitrary IPs)

**TL;DR: How can I define the value of a custom swift flag or compiler variable, something I can assign to a variable in a `plist`, at build time with a bash script?**

Comment: If I understand your goal, you should be able to combine the `${NODE_JS_IP}` idea with option 1 to make this work.  Within the Xcode build settings, add a user-defined setting called `NODE_JS_IP` with the address as its value.  Then add a build phase that uses the macro expansion for plist variable replacement.

Comment: @PhillipMills my question is what the mechanics of setting NODE_JS_IP with the address would be. An `export` statement, or something?

Comment: Go to Xcode's build settings for your target.  Click on a `+` sign near the top middle of the screen.  Select "Add User-defined Setting".

Comment: I don't think I'm being clear: I understand how to create a user defined setting. My question is; how would I put the *address* (that is, the *value* of the setting) in? Are you suggesting I manually change it every time my IP changes?

Comment: I do what you described in #2.  Make 1 plist with the prod credentials that only gets compiled into the main app target and a separate one with the same name that gets compiled into the test target.  You can use plist buddy to modify the test target plist https://www.willowtreeapps.com/ideas/using-plistbuddy-to-inject-app-secrets-and-keys-at-build-time

Comment: @pixelrevision Its a good idea but still runs into the problem I had with #2, and the article linked states it: "Note that this does not fully protect app keys and secrets." In my case, that's an IP.